# Combining two columns to generate index in pd Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Firstly, excuses if this has been asked and answered.
I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417956/combine-values-of-two-columns-of-dataframe-into-one-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644937/combine-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-pandas), went through the titles of recommended duplicates and try to use search engines, but cannot seem to come up with the right keyword.

#### problem

My problem is the following: given a dataframe with two "identifier" columns, I want to create an index that uniquely describes each combination of values in the two columns:

For instance: column 'a' has value 0, and column 'b' has value '0' and this should get index number 1. Same combinations should map to the same value.

#### approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.randint(0,3,10),
    'b': np.random.randint(0,3,10),
    'c': np.random.randint(0,10,10)
})

mapping = [(*key, i+1) for i, key in enumerate(df.groupby(by=['a', 'b']).groups.keys())]
crutch = pd.DataFrame(mapping, columns=['a', 'b', 'new_index'])
df = df.merge(crutch, left_on=['a', 'b'], right_on=['a', 'b'])
```

This works, but it seems like there should be something built into pandas that I am missing.

#### question

So, is there something built into pandas that would help and that I could not figure out?

#### thanks

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Following pandas notation, it should be index 0

Comment: I want to use the 1-index downstream, so thought I would add it there. But you are correct of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)

```
df['new_index'] = df.groupby(['a','b']).ngroup().add(1)
print(df)
   a  b  c  new_index
0  2  1  4          6
1  1  1  5          3
2  1  1  8          3
3  1  1  2          3
4  2  2  8          7
5  2  2  5          7
6  2  0  8          5
7  0  1  7          1
8  1  2  5          4
9  0  2  5          2
```